# Error:(42, 30) error: package com.google.android.gcm does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio

I have install the gcm from sdk but after than it's also not worked and give this error.

```
C:\Users\name\projectname\app\src\main\java\com\projectname\act\Login.java
    Error:(42, 30) error: package com.google.android.gcm does not exist
    Error:(124, 3) error: cannot find symbol variable GCMRegistrar
    Error:(127, 3) error: cannot find symbol variable GCMRegistrar
    Error:(358, 12) error: cannot find symbol variable GCMRegistrar
    Error:(362, 4) error: cannot find symbol variable GCMRegistrar
    Error:(365, 8) error: cannot find symbol variable GCMRegistrar
    Error:(462, 4) error: cannot find symbol variable GCMRegistrar
C:\Users\name\projectname\app\src\main\java\com\projectname\act\ServerUtilities.java
    Error:(17, 30) error: package com.google.android.gcm does not exist
    Error:(63, 17) error: cannot find symbol variable GCMRegistrar
    Error:(105, 13) error: cannot find symbol variable GCMRegistrar
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

google play services also imported
here is my build.gradle file below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:21'
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.vibrantmeetme.act"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 21
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

}
```

if any one have solution so please give

Comment: Can you paste your build script?

Comment: yes here is my build script below

Comment: Hey, what I meant by build script is the actual logic that builds your apk, either a pom.xml if you use maven or a build.gradle if you use gradle.

Comment: it is build.gradle file which i posted

Comment: my bad I didn't refresh the page before answering, please my comment in your below answer

Comment: Add  missing the libraries from extras\google\gcm\gcm-server\dist\gcm-server.jar and its dependencies. Add these to the libs folder under this project and try again.

Comment: do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `com.google.android.gcm` with `com.google.android.gms.gcm` in your imports

Comment: Whenever I import com.google.android.gms.gcm it becomes red text on Android Studio and is removed. I have compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+' on my gradle. Any idea why?

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had to use:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
```

so I had to explicitly reference the gcm module

Comment: i checked the google docs also even that does not say we need this dependency. Google samples on github is using entire play-service which will create issue on dex limit